# How do I get an object and update multiple fields in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I want to get an object using primary key, update the object and return it. The examples I saw showing me to update each fields. Something like this:

```
blog_post = session.query(BlogPost).get(blog_post_id)
blog_post.name = 'something'
blog_post.author = 'something'
session.commit()
```

Problem is I have multiple fields. I don't like updating each field like above. I know I could do something like this:

```
session.query(BlogPost).filter(blog_post_id).update(data)
session.commit()
```

But I want the object I updated and I don't want to query again. Ideally, I would like something like this (following doesn't work, sqlalchemy object has no `update` method):

```
blog_post = session.query(BlogPost).get(blog_post_id)
blog_post.update(data)
session.commit()
```

What I can do is, I can query and update. And later, fetch the object again. Or I can use a `for` loop and update each of the fields. But something tells me that it should be already present in sqlalchemy.

Comment: what do you mean with "I don't like updating each field"? in your first code snippet you only have to update the fields that really need to change; the other filelds will keep their value.

Comment: I meant... I have lots of fields and I don't like to update each of them manually. I have updated the question.

Comment: you need to write `BlogPost.update(self, ...)` method. sqlalchemy can not know what you want to update and what needs to remain the same.